# Setting up journal path in mongod.conf?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo v2.6 I am trying to setup  path in mongod.conf but not sure what parameter name is called or whether mongo has one ?  For instance for data, mongo uses this parameter: dbpath and for mongo logs, it uses this parameter: logpath

I am trying to find the parameter path name for journal ? The goal is to separate the journal logs from getting created in the data path & put them on separate volume.. is this doable ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way of specifying the journal path in the config file, but there is a a fair workaround for this matter.

As mentioned in this [DB StackExchange Topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56337/how-to-separate-mongodb-journal), the person who provided the top answer recommends creating a symbolic link to a new mountpoint for the default journal folder, which is a sub-directory of the `dbpath` folder, named `journal`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, you are right, there is no such a thing. Mongo keeps [data] & [journals] on the same path by default. One of the reasons I wanted to separate journal logs from data is to improve performance - similar to what we do with Oracle Archive Logs, we always keep them on their own volume separating them from the data files. But one important caveat that led me NOT to mess with JOURNAL path is the fact that I will loose the ability to do snapshot. I found that out from other resources. Backups/Snapshots are very critical, so I am keeping journals where they are :)